# Compute integral of $e^{i\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}/(a^2+x^2)$ over $\mathbb{R}$, why is it wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to compute this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{a^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

But I'm a little bit rusty with complex analysis ... What I've been trying to do so far is the following using cauchy lemma ($\gamma$ goes straight from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and do half-circle from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ on the upper part of the complex plan):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{a^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{z^2+a^2}}}{a^2+z^2}\mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i \;\mathrm{Res}(ai)$$
And then computing the residue from the pole on the imaginary axis:
$$\mathrm{Res}(ai) = \frac{e^{i\sqrt{a^2-a^2}}}{2ia} = \frac{1}{2ia}$$
and then the result is obvisously wrong, as this integral cannot have imaginary part equal zero ...
So I wonder:

1. Why is it wrong to do that ?
2. How can I compute this integral ? Numerically I guess the result is gonna have something to do with Hankel function but I'd like a mathematical proof.

Thank you.

Comment: Function $\sqrt{z^2+a^2}$ is not analytic in the upper semi-plane (it has a branching point at $z=-a$) so you cannot use Cauchy's integral theorem in this way. Besides, you would  need to check that the integral over the semicircle that closes the contour vanishes in the limit.

Comment: Besides, the factor $i$ in the denominator cancels against the $i$ in the numerator....

Comment: @AdamLatosiński should I use another contour ? Maybe one that goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ do a quarter circle, then goes down to $ia$ following the

Comment: @M.Wind yes I see but how can this be helpful ?

Comment: Let $a > 0$ and $a^2 u^2 = x^2 + a^2$. The Fourier transform of $2 (u^2 - 1)^{-1/2} [u > 1]$ is $\pi i H_0^{(1)}(a)$, so your integral is $(\pi/a) \int_a^\infty H_0^{(1)}(t) \, dt$. An antiderivative of $H_0^{(1)}$ has a closed form in terms of Hankel and Struve functions.

Comment: @Maxim but if I substitute with $a^2u^2$ there's gonna be a $u$ at the denominator, the computation you give is valid for $e^{i\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}/\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ no ? am i mistaken ?

Comment: The integration property of the Fourier transform gives the antiderivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Maxim I was able to compute this integral, here is a more detailed solution:

We start with the substitution $u^2a^2=x^2+a^2$, that leads to $\mathrm{d}x = ua^2\mathrm{d}u/\sqrt{u^2-1}$ thus:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{a^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x =
2\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{i\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{a^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x = 
\frac{2}{a}\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{iau}}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}\mathrm{d}u$$
We can now write it as a fourier tranform for $u>1$:

$$\frac{2}{a}\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{iau}}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}\mathrm{d}u = \frac{2}{a}\mathcal{F}\left(u\mapsto\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)(a) =  \frac{1}{ai}\int_a^{+\infty}\mathcal{F}\left(u\mapsto\frac{2}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

we can conclude introducing the Hankel function:

$$\frac{1}{ai}\int_a^{+\infty}\mathcal{F}\left(u\mapsto\frac{2}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\right)(t)\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\pi}{a}\int_a^{+\infty}H^{(1)}_0(t)\mathrm{d}t $$